# fake `.gz` raise IOError, 'Not a gzipped file'

Tags: python, try-catch, gzip

Let's say I have a fake gz file `test.bson.gz` generated by `echo "hello world" > test.bson.gz`, and I have tried:

```
try:
    bson_file = gzip.open('test.bson.gz', mode='rb')
except:
    print("cannot open")
```

No exception will be caught here. (Really strange, since this is not a valid gz...)

Then I do:

```
data = bson_file.read(4)
```

I will get:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 190, in _read_gzip_header
    raise IOError, 'Not a gzipped file'
IOError: Not a gzipped file
```

Is there any way that I can determine (even catch error) whether this .gz is valid when I try to open it, not wait until I wanna read it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`gzip.peek(n)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile.peek):

> Read *n* uncompressed bytes without advancing the file position.

```
try:
    bson_file = gzip.open('test.bson.gz', mode='rb')
    bson_file.peek(1)
except OSError:
    print("cannot open")
```

That way you will catch the error without consuming the file contents.

Hint: You should avoid catching all errors unconditionally. I added `except OSError`, because `IOError` was merged to `OSError` in Python 3.3 - see [PEP3151](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3151/).

Comment: Wait... It seems that this code does not work for valid BSON. Try `bson_file.peek(1)` for a valid `.bson.gz`, and you will see that it can still catch the error.